# check props value in child component if available

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I'm working currently with `BootstrapVue`.

I have a `b-dropdown` in my parent.vue where I can select a object of a JSON-File and convert it into an array because I need the length of this json object. *This works fine!!*

**My problem** is that I need to check in my `parent.vue` if something was selected - so if `this.arrayLength` is higher than 0 *(until this point it works all well!)*. If this is true, it should use and show `addElementsNotClickable()` in my `child.vue` where no elements can be added (count of the inputs are equal to length of array) - otherwise it should use and show my button `addElement()` where multiple elements can be added manually.

But I'm not able to check in my child.vue if `arrayLenght > 0`... **AND** i don't know what to use on second button e.g @change(??) How can I solve that?

Many thanks! I've tried to be as detailed as I can!

**Additional Info**: I get no error codes!!

my parent.vue:

```
methods: {
  inputedValue(input, index) {
    var array = [];
    const item= this.json.find((i) => i.Number === input);
    for (let key in item.ID) {
      array.push(item.ID[key]);
    }
    if(array.length > 0) {
      this.getIndex = index;
      this.getDataArray = array;
      this.getLengthArray = array.length;
    }
  }
}
```

my child.vue (template)

```
<div class="mt-4 mb-5 ml-3 mr-3">
  <b-button v-if="!hide" @click="addElement" variant="block">Add Element</b-button>
  <b-button v-if="hide" @???="addElementNotClickable" variant="block">Not clickable ! </b-button>
</div>
```

my child.vue (script)

```
methods: {
  addElementsNotClickable() {
      for(let i = 1; i < this.arrayLength; i++) {
        this.inputs.push({})
      }
  },

  addElement() {
      this.inputs.push({})   
  },
}

data() {
  return {
    inputs: [{}]
    arrayLength: this.getLengthArray,
    arrayIndex: this.getIndex,
    hide: false,
}

props: [
    "getLengthArray",
    "getIndex"
    ],
```

Comment: So to see if we understood. You would like to add a listener to your `NOT CLICKABLE` div if `arrayIndex > 0`? The question doesn't seem very clear

Comment: this is first Thing i Need - but the bigger problem is how to check in my Child.vue if array.length > 0

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how components should work in Vue. In short you can understand them by:

> parent send props down and child send events up

[image: vue component events]

What you are looking for is that whenever your `arrayLength` updates, you send an event to the parent. Then, it is the responsibility of the parent to handle that event. In this case, the parent would receive the event and store the length of the array.

### Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div> 
    <child @arrayLenght:update="onArrayLenghtUpdate"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => {
    arrayLength: 0,
  },
  methods: {
    onArrayLenghtUpdate(length) {
      this.arrayLength = length;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

### Child.vue

```
<template>  ... </template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    arrayLength: 0,
  }),
  watch: {
    arrayLenghth: function (newLenght) {
       this.$emit('arrayLenght:update', newLenght);
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the standard way and extremely useful if your `Parent` and `Child` aren't highly coupled together. If they are dependent on each other (you won't use `Child.vue` anywhere else in the app. Just as direct child of `Parent.vue`) then you can use the `inject/provide` approach. This approach is beyond the scope of this answer, feel free to read an [article on it](https://medium.com/js-dojo/the-magic-of-provide-inject-a27041df33b2)

Comment: I understand how ```components``` work. But I need to send a prop from my parent because their I'm selecting my ```option``` - in my child I need to check for each element if something was selected. So my parent is likely like a navbar and my child is everything in this navbar.

Comment: But thanks for your help !